# Изолинии с равным временем прибытия из определенной точки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне понадобилось создать на карте изолинии с равным временем прибытия (пешком) из определенной точки. Это должно быть в виде полигонов для 5, 10, 15 и 20 минут. Можно ли это автоматизировать и сделать через JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1):

Автоматически построить такую изолинию в JS API можно, используя пешеходную маршрутизацию, но это будет не оптимально и потребуется делать много запросов к сервисам Яндекса (скорее всего вы не уложитесь в лимиты бесплатного использования).

Если изолиния уже рассчитана и известны координаты, то нарисовать многоугольник на карте уже [элементарно](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon?from=SO).